# How to make accordion type side bar layout in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want the selectInput and numericInput in an accordion type sidebar.
I looked at bsplus package where it has a function called **bs_accordion()** and **bsbs_accordion_sidebar()**. How to use those functions or are there other packages to create accordion type sidebar.

Sample Code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    
    sidebarPanel(

      
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)

    ),

    
    mainPanel(

      
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

 
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")

    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Desired Sample Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bsplus` package one option to achieve your desired result would be to use `bs_accordion` in `sidebarPanel`. To add sections or panels to the accordion you have to use `bs_append`. Additionally I use `bs_set_opts(use_heading_link = TRUE)` to make the `"entire panel heading clickable"` (See `?bs_accordion`).

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarPanel(
    bs_accordion(
      id = "accordion"
    )  |> 
      bs_set_opts(
        use_heading_link = TRUE
      ) |> 
      bs_append(
        title = "Section 1",
        content = sliderInput(
          inputId = "bins",
          label = "Number of bins:",
          min = 1,
          max = 50,
          value = 30
        )
      ) |>
      bs_append(
        title = "Section 2",
        content = selectInput(
          inputId = "color",
          label = "Fill color",
          choices = c("#75AADB", "grey")
        )
      )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    hist(x,
         breaks = bins, col = input$color, border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. What are some other packages to get similar result

Comment: I tried to output table into the accordion but didn't work

Comment: Hm. Adding a table works fine for me. I just tried with `bs_append(title = "Section 3", content = tableOutput(outputId = "table"))` and `output$table <- renderTable({ dplyr::count(mtcars, cyl) })`. Another option to add an accordion would be to use `shinydashboardplus` .